# Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService error in selenium standalone server

Tags: java, selenium, server, webdriver

I am trying to execute the attached code and getting the below error,

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision:
>   '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z' System info: host: 'OHM',
>   ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown

```
package com.pluralsight;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class RemoteWebDriverDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"E:\\Selenium\\Chrome_driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), 
            DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
String baseUrl = "http://GOOGLE.com";

    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");

    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("Lord Krishna");
    searchBox.submit();

    WebElement imagesLink = 
driver.findElements(By.linkText("Images")).get(0);
    imagesLink.click();


    }

}
```

Comment: what's your chrome driver version and your browser version?

Comment: Chrome Driver is 2.40 version and browser version is 67.0.3396.99

Comment: And I am using selenium version 3.13

Comment: What are your commands to run your grid - hub & node ?

Comment: I just ran the java jar- selenium-standalone-3.13.jar